# How can i remove unused CSS and Javascript from react built website?

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm actually looking for something where I can reduce the unused JS and CSS.....Since The Website Is Built On a website Please Tell me how to reduce unused Js and CSS from the Website

Here Is Image :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRMxo.png)